# some font not showing in myapp from ios

Tags: iphone, ios7, fonts

1. There are Four font i using in myapp.
2. i have adding four font ttf file in info.plist.
3. i using each and every font. but only one font not working in my app.

   **Font Lists are**
4. BellGothicStd-Light.ttf
5. digiface.ttf
6. rbno2-light-alternative.ttf
7. EnhancedDotDigital-7.ttf

   - Working fonts are 4,5,6.
   - 7th font are not worked in my app

What is the reason for that?

- Any not supporting font are in ios plateform.
  pls tell any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

The font is working just fine. Here are the steps I have followed to get it working:

1. [Downloaded the font](http://www.fonts2u.com/enhanced-dot-digital-7.font) and added it into my project
2. Make sure that the font file is added to the correct target
3. Added the font in `Fonts provided by application` (info.plist) as `enhanced_dot_digital-7.ttf` (the filename of the font)
4. Used the font like this

`myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"EnhancedDotDigital-7" size:17.0f];`

Where the font name is the Postscript name of the font (it's listed on the linked website. You can also find out about this on Font Book app). So my guess is that you either forgot to add the font in to the target or used a different name in the last step. I hope that this makes sense

[image]