# Unable to set custom font for the UILabel in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uifont, info.plist

I am unable to set custom font for the UILabel in XCode.

This is what I've tried:

- Download "JennaSue" font -- http://www.dafont.com/jenna-sue.font
- Open "app-info.plist" under "Supporting Files" folder
- Add new row in the list with key "Fonts provided by application"
- In this array add "JennaSue.ttf"
- Use it in the code like this:

`self.someLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"JennaSue" size:14];`

And nothing happens -- the default font is visible.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: tried self.someLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Jenna-sue" size:14]; ?

Comment: as @user3781721 said i think you forgot .ttf extension

Comment: Make sure you have added the font to your **target** and pass the _Postscript_ name to `fontWithName:size:` (you can find about it in the Font Book app). See also this relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605844/some-font-not-showing-in-myapp-from-ios/24606107#24606107

Comment: Can you check if the ttf file you included is present in your "targets>buildPhases> compile sources"..sometimes the reference to the file is lost while importing

Comment: @Geet Yes, there is no such file. I've add it but nothing happens

Comment: if the file is not in Compile sources then try adding it by clicking the "+" sign below compile source, and navigate to your project and chose your TTF file and clilck on Add File and try to run again

Comment: @Geet Nothing happens

Answer (score 14):

Be sure your font is in Bundle Resources. For some reason Xcode it is not importing custom font properly most of the time:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've got the font working:

[image]

Example code: [here](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/JennaSueFONTExample)

Comment: I also had to add it to the Info.plist and add: Fonts provided by application: filename

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to your project's `info.plist` file,
2. Right click and select `Add row`,
3. Type `Fonts provided by application` in the new row,
4. Type in the desired font name as items for this key.
5. **Drag and drop the font file into the project,**
6. Apply it to the text you want:

`someLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"JennaSue" size: 12.0];`

I think you've missed step 5 up there.

**Update:** When doing step 5, remember to check the marks for copying the actual file into project directory:

[image]
Remember to clean your project by pressing "command+alt+shift+K" (IRRC!)
And then go to your

and then go to your project's Build Phases, and make sure you can see your `.ttf` file file among the resource files:

[image]

P.S. I'm not on my Mac at the moment, so I used screenshots from [this tutorial](http://paulsolt.com/2012/03/iphone-unit-testing-explained-part-ii/). That's why I grayed out the unnecessary lines for your issue.

Comment: No, i've put this file in the "Supporting files" folder

Comment: Uh, Ok. But make sure Xcode has actually received and digested the file, as well! Since it's just crap at recognizing added files sometimes. Am updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check this code:

```
 NSArray *names = [UIFont familyNames];
 NSLog(@"Font FamilyNames : ");
 for (NSString *name in names) {
     NSLog(@"Font Family:  %@",name);
     NSArray *fontFaces = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:name];
     for (NSString *fname in fontFaces) {
          NSLog(@"   %@",fname);
     }
  }

  self.someLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"use correct name" size:self.someLabel.font.pointSize];
```

and use the same name printed with NSLog.

Answer (score 1):

After adding custom font to Xcode don't forget to add font to plist.
`Project settings` > `Info` > `Custom IOS target properties`

[image]
Add property `Fonts provided by application` and type your custom font(filename of font file). 
Then you can use that code example
`self.someLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"JennaSue" size:14];`

Notice: make sure that you use right font name in code. To do that you should add this font to your Mac's font book, open font book, choose that font and check the right name font.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
self.someLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"JennaSue.ttf" size:self.someLabel.font.pointSize];
```

Comment: Maybe I need to add the .ttf file in the specific folder? I've put it in the "Supporting files" folder too

Answer (score 0):

i used following code and it's done

```
 UILabel * lblTest = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 200, 100)];

    lblTest.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"JennaSue" size:25.0];
    lblTest.text = @"Hello World";

    [self.view addSubview:lblTest];
```

and if still not working looking at your system font book and search that font and **That Font you have to use to get it work**

also try this  `lblTest.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Jenna Sue" size:25.0];`

Answer (score 0):

is the file visible in Compile Source now…if yes then you may have the font name wrong..sometimes the font names are different then their file name…try running a

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) 
{ 
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName])
    { 
       NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
    }
}
```

this lines of code..you will be able to see the actual name of the font and use that name instead

Comment: Yes, it is listed in "Compile sources" now, but this code doesn't print the name of this font

Comment: then it means your file hasn't been detected….try to delete the file from your project and re import it also include it once again in your info.plist..also can you check if your font is a actually a TTF(True Type Font)..if the anything else then this, then that can be your problem

Answer (score 0):

The font could be corrupted or something. I tried the solutions provided by Gabriel.Massana & Neeku and it worked on some fonts. Try adding the font to your Mac. If it showed verification problem, most probably it's not gonna work in your app. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is @Ritu's answer in Swift 2. Just put this in your AppDelegate, or in viewDidLoad method of your View Controller:

```
let names = UIFont.familyNames()
for name in names {
   print("Font Family: \(name)")
   let fontFaces = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(name)
   for fname in fontFaces {
      print("            \(fname)")
   }
}
```

You will have all your font names in console log, just copy and paste the one you need in your code.